# code igniter url doubling

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-routing, codeigniter-form-helper

I'm having an issue where when I submit a form where the submit URL the just appends to the existing URL instead of replacing it.

It is supposed to be:

```
localhost/DataConnect/index.php/sites/MakeEdit/1
```

But instead I get:

```
localhost/DataConnect/index.php/sites/EditSite/localhost/DataConnect/index.php/sites/MakeEdit/1
```

I open the form with:

```
echo form_open('sites/MakeEdit/'.$site['ID'],$attributes,$hidden);
```

So I.m not real sure where I am going wrong. If there is any more information I  can provide please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
echo form_open(base_url().'sites/MakeEdit/'.$site['ID'],$attributes,$hidden);
```

and don't forget to call the url helper on your controller:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: This just made the URL longer,
    http://localhost/DataConnect/index.php/sites/EditSite/localhost/DataConnect/index.php/localhost/DataConnect/sites/MakeEdit/1